# Minimum resolution for Tablet devices media query?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have set desktop view starting from 768px on my site using media query min-width statement. This works OK for Apple tablets.

Are there smaller resolutions of tablets for which I can set desktop view using media query statements? 600 px min-width?

Comment: 768 x 1024 is the size of the iPad Mini I don't think a tablet could be smaller than this, else you will need to plan for the phone

Comment: Ok thanks I’ll leave desktop view at min 768px then.

Comment: Personally I use the same sizes as Bootstrap, I guess they choose them wisely : 576 < 768 < 992 < 1200.

Comment: @ElliotYoYo and can you state them please?

Comment: They are in my previous comment, I edited it just after sending it.
You can find them here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/